# Math operation results from the same table depending on specific id

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I'm trying to select a table displaying the results of operations performed on certain columns with specific IDs in SQL Server.

The `EventLog` table contains various `EventId`s representing different game events (17 = death, 21 = kill). I'm trying to get the SUM and AVG of the FloatResult column for death events, and the total number of records for kill events, then display them on a table vs. class type.

```
select 
    e.Class, a.TotalLifetime, a.AverageLifetime, b.TotalKills
from 
    EventLog e 
join 
    (select 
         e1.Class, 
         SUM(e1.FloatResult) as TotalLifetime, 
         AVG(e1.FloatResult) as AverageLifetime
     from 
         EventLog e1
     join 
         Maps m on e1.MapId = m.Id
     where 
         e1.EventId = 17 and
         m.MapName like '%my_map' and 
         e1.EventTime >= '2013-07-04' and
         e1.EventTime <= DATEADD(d, 1, '2013-07-05')
     group by 
         e1.Class) as a on e.Class = a.Class
join (
    select e2.Class, count(*) as TotalKills
    from EventLog e2 
    join Maps m on e2.MapId = m.Id
    where e2.EventId = 21 and
    m.MapName like '%my_map' and 
        e2.EventTime >= '2013-07-04' and
        e2.EventTime <= DATEADD(d, 1, '2013-07-05')
    group by e2.Class
) as b on e.Class = b.Class
group by e.Class
```

The ideal result would be:

```
Class  TotalLifeTime AverageLifetime TotalKills
0      563.45        30.5            100
1      766.6         12.56           20
etc...
```

This results in SQL Server saying:

> Error line 1: Column 'a.TotalLifetime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause..

However I don't want to group by this value, only by class.

Is there a better way to formulate this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pre-summarizing all the data fields by `class`.  Hence, you do not need to aggregate again at the outermost level.  You only need to get the distinct classes from `EventLog`:

```
select 
    e.Class, a.TotalLifetime, a.AverageLifetime, b.TotalKills
from 
    (select distinct class from EventLog e
    ) e
left outer join 
    (select 
         e1.Class, 
         SUM(e1.FloatResult) as TotalLifetime, 
         AVG(e1.FloatResult) as AverageLifetime
     from 
         EventLog e1
     join 
         Maps m on e1.MapId = m.Id
     where 
         e1.EventId = 17 and
         m.MapName like '%my_map' and 
         e1.EventTime >= '2013-07-04' and
         e1.EventTime <= DATEADD(d, 1, '2013-07-05')
     group by 
         e1.Class) as a on e.Class = a.Class
left outer join (
    select e2.Class, count(*) as TotalKills
    from EventLog e2 
    join Maps m on e2.MapId = m.Id
    where e2.EventId = 21 and
    m.MapName like '%my_map' and 
        e2.EventTime >= '2013-07-04' and
        e2.EventTime <= DATEADD(d, 1, '2013-07-05')
    group by e2.Class
) as b on e.Class = b.Class;
```

I also changed the `join`s to `left outer join`s to keep all the classes.